# converting a date from SQL Server to C# and then to javascript gives different results on US vs. London webserver

Tags: c#, javascript, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, date

I have an asp.net mvc calendar application (using jquery ui datepicker) and i am running into a weird situation where when i test on a US webserver i see a certain date and when i test on a London web server i see a different date (the date before)

Here are the details:

I am storing a date in sql server as:

```
 2010-09-16 00:00:00.000
```

I am then loading that into C# DateTime object.

I need to pass that down as part of a json object to my clientside javascript so i was suggested this solution:

```
jsonobject.Date = UnixTicks(a.Date),
```

where **UnixTicks** is:

```
private static double UnixTicks(DateTime dt)
    {
        DateTime d1 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        DateTime d2 = dt.ToUniversalTime();
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(d2.Ticks - d1.Ticks);
        return ts.TotalMilliseconds;
    }
```

I am then converting it to a javascript date by using this code below on the client side:

```
var d = new Date(jsonobject.Date);
```

does anyone know why given a US server or a London server i would get back a different date.  At first, i thought it was the

```
 DateTime d2 = dt.ToUniversalTime();
```

but i changed that to:

```
 DateTime d2 = dt;
```

and still saw the same issue. (on London web server date would show up 1 day prior to the US web server)

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're storing local time in the database instead of UTC, then you could get different dates back when converting back to local time.  Make sure your dates are converted to UTC *before* you commit them to the database.  If you want everyone to always see the same date no matter where they are, always return the UTC date- do not convert back to local time.

Comment: are you saying do this on the javascript side or on the C# side ??

Comment: It depends on what you want.  If you want everyone to see the same date no matter what, make sure you are *both* storing the date as UTC, and presenting it as UTC with no conversion when you send it in your json.  This may mean you have to convert *to* UTC on the way to the database, depending on how those dates are entered.

Comment: im confused.  I have a date which is November 19th, 2010.  i dont have any interest in dealing with time at all and thus UTC or timezone.  Is there not a reason why i can't just keep it as the same date front to back.  maybe just pass as a string ??

Comment: @ooo:  You may be able to get around the problem by dealing with short date time formats, but I haven't tried this specifically so I can't be sure.  I wouldn't store dates as strings, or you'll eventually come back to this problem again when you have to convert them back into dates.

Comment: i formatted at "March 14, 2010" as a string and problem went away

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a localization issue.  You need to store your DateTime in the same Time Zone and account for different Date formatting.  For instance, September 1st, 2010 in the US is formatted "9/1/2010" and in the UK it's formatted "1/9/2010".  If you're looking at that as a US date, you're going to be looking at January 9th, 2010.

Comment: its not that i am getting 1/9 versions 9/1.  i am just getting 1 day off

Comment: I was listing that date format just as something to look out for.  Other possibilities would be time zones, incorrect time on one of the machines, or Daylight Savings.  I know Daylight Savings was a pain a few years back when the US changed the date and the UK did not.

Comment: i basically want to eliminate any use of time at all.  I just want to deal with the date front to back.  is there anyway to just do this?  should i just convert to string.

Comment: I see what you're saying and honestly don't know why the date is coming back different without the ability to test and debug myself.  If you used a string, as you suggested, the problem would certainly disappear (but you still need to watch for the date formatting difference -- I would use a format like "Jan 1 2010")

Comment: i formatted at "March 14, 2010" as a string and problem went away

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to completely ignore the time zone and localization issue, just present the dates as strings to your application:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar(10),YourDatetimeColumn,111) AS StringDate1  --YYYY/MM/DD
   ,CONVERT(varchar(10),YourDatetimeColumn,121) AS StringDate2  --YYYY-MM-DD
    FROM ...
```

and then just use them within the application like regular string data and they will not change or be adjusted for you.